# Survival of streptococcus after my scarlet fever

Tags: microbiology, bacteriology, epidemiology

I'm currently sick because of scarlet fever but I got treated with antibiotics. I know that after 1.5 day using antibiotics the streptococci I release at home are dangerous anymore. But my question is, what about the streptococci I've spread before? I've read that *Streptococcus pyogenes* can survive 3 days to 6.5 months outside the host, does that mean, I have to disinfect the whole house? And if so, with what should I desinfect? I worked heavily on the laptop, how do I desinfect that? Thank you.

Comment: Seeing that the OP is enquiring about the survivability of a virus outside a host, I don't consider this a medical question.

Comment: @TheLastWord .... "*does that mean, I have to desinfect the whole house? And if so, with what should I desinfect?*": This is a health advice

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't find any medical/health stackexchange, and my question is about the survival of a bacteria, why is that not related to biology and bacteriology? I highly doubt that many physician that know. I just want to know, how long they survive and how big the danger of infection is, implying whether I have to desinfect some thing or not.

Comment: Please see here to understand how health advice works:http://meta.biology.stackexchange.com/questions/2885/what-is-health-advice?noredirect=1#comment2709_2885

Comment: If you can remove the data about the personal sickness and recovery, your question won't be considered health advice anymore.

Comment: It is hard to answer this question. There is an http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infectious_dose by every disease, so you might don't need to disinfect the whole house. (I don't know the exact number by S. pyogenes, it probably depends on host.) You can reduce the risk by cleaning the tools you touch most frequently. You should find something which does not damage the plastic your laptop is made of.

@TheLastWord S. pyogenes is a bacteria and not a virus. Btw. I don't think this is a medical question either, it is about disinfection and not about how to cure the disease.

Comment: @inf3rno This was the answer I've been looking for. I'm not sick anymore, so it's not a health advice question but a general question about the bacteria itself.

Comment: @AndSchu Be aware that you are more (but not completely) resistant to further infection, than people around you who never got the disease.

Comment: `"Note: Septic sore throat, scarlet fever and other pyogenic and septicemic syndromes are also infrequently acquired from ingestion (low infectious dose of <1000 organisms) of contaminated food (onset after 1-3 days)"` http://www.life.umd.edu/classroom/bsci424/PathogenDescriptions/Streptococcus.htm So I think you don't need many of them to get infected. If somebody has your S. pyogenes strain in they flora, then they probably need a much higher dose to become ill. Btw. this is just my opinion, I don't want to look for articles, so I won't post an answer.

Comment: @anongoodnurse Fine, I was hasty and put that comment up doesn't mean you be all sarcastic about it.

Comment: @TheLastWord - It was unkind, maybe, but not sarcastic. Haste makes spilled milk.

Answer (score 2):

The Streptococci are a part of the normal human flora.

> The streptococci are widely distributed in nature and frequently form part of the normal human flora (seeTable 29-1). Approximately 5-15% of humans carry S pyogenes or S agalactiae in the nasopharynx.

Please see:http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK7611/#!po=51.4706 for more details on epidemiology of streptococci.

As 5-15% humans have it in their nasopharynx, it is not really possible to maintain streptococci free environment. It will get repopulated quickly.

Usually the reason you get infected is because of some alteration in your normal flora.

> S pneumoniae and, to a lesser extent, S pyogenes are part of the normal human nasopharyngeal flora. Their numbers are usually limited by competition from the nasopharyngeal microbial ecosystem and by nonspecific host defense mechanisms, but failure of these mechanisms can result in disease. More often disease results from the acquisition of a new strain following alteration of the normal flora. (From the same article, under pathogenesis)

So basically disinfecting wont help much as humans have the streptococci as a part of their normal flora. And it is very likely that the people you live with or come in contact with regularly have the streptococci already in their flora (either they got it from you or they originally had it themselves).

Comment: If something is wrong please tell it in the comments along with down voting so that the OP can get the correct view!

Comment: If someone simply downvotes for the sake of downvoting then I don't mind! Have fun :)

Comment: I don't think this is true. There are many strains of S. pyogenes, and s/he is probably infected with a new one.

Comment: I pointed it out in the second quote, that a new strain (a change in flora) can cause it @inf3rno

Comment: With this logic we can call every infection as "change in the flora"...

Comment: That is what the paper said. I did not tell anything on my own. Well, if you choose to disagree, I can't help it. @inf3rno

Comment: I think the wording of the article is not the best, there are lot of opportunistic pathogens which work the way they described, e.g. by C. difficile we use to talk about infection and rarely about the change of normal flora. Every pathogen has an infectious dose, so by disinfecting the house or the tools they frequently used, they can reduce the risk of somebody else gets infected. I think this is independent of whether somebody already got the new strain. (That probably increases the infectious dose, but does not make you totally protected.)

Comment: The fact remains that the host may get infected with normal flora strains too due to some alteration in the host and or the flora. Are you telling this mechanism is wrong? @inf3rno

Comment: Pathogen which gets outside the body has to compete with the normal flora which is already there outside the body. The advantages it enjoyed inside the body due to its increased virulence (thus ablity to penetrate host defence) won't help it outside the host where it has to compete with other micro-organisms against which it has no special supressing effect. So its replication and survival is not a surety

Comment: "The fact remains that the host may get infected with normal flora strains too due to some alteration in the host and or the flora." - Ofc. this is true. If we are talking about a new strain, then we cannot say that it was originally part of the host's flora, so we call it infection. By S. pyogenes, getting infected with a new strain typically causes disease (which in rare cases can lead to death). After that the host's immune system and other microbes in the flora learn to deal with the new strain.

Comment: It will probably die outside of the host after a while, but it is better to make this faster with disinfection, so you will protect those who are not infected. I don't know the exact data about how S. pyogenes survives outside the body, so that's all I can say currently. gn8! :-)

Comment: Good night! Have a good sleep!